# Traverse up and down through javascript array-hash tree

Tags: javascript, json, tree

There is simple scenario: my web app queries my server and obtain JSON object. It represents tree-like structure:

```
[
  {
    some: info,
    other:info
  },
  {
    some: info,
    other:info
  },
  {
    children:
    [
       {
         some: info,
         other:info
       },
       {
         some: info,
         other:info
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't need to iterate through it just after it has been obtained, I need to have something like a pointer to the current node (a leaf of the tree). The problem is that after I set pointer to say first child of the third subtree in my example, pointer 'forgets' from where it got down here. What is the most concise practice in the case?

Comment: Most commonly you would build a stack (i.e., an array) ob object references as you do the recursion. You could then refer to `stack[0]` as the current parent, `stack[1]` as the one next higher up, and so on (with the added benefit that stack length equals recursion depth, if you care for that bit of info).

Comment: @Tomalak yeah, I incline to the solution too. Just don't like iteration function to have that global info ) Thank you anyway!